# Maximum conditions in Switch statement in Tableau-Excel connection

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, switch-statement, tableau-api

I am working on a SQL in Tableau Desktop for extracting data from an Excel spreadsheet.

I have 125 subject codes to be categorized in 24 different departments.

I am using "Switch" statement for the same. The query works perfectly fine if I enter 13 different cases, however, it gives me below error when I try to input more than 13 cases.

> *Database error 0x80040E14: Expression too complex in query expression 'Switch([Subjectcode] in ("21:003"),"AF",[Subjectcode] in
>   ("21:080","21:082","21:089","26:561"),"ACM",[Subjectcode] in
>   ("21:014"),"AAAF",[Subjectcode] in ('.*

Is there a limit for the number of cases that can be input to the Switch statement?

Please Note: I cannot use "IF..ELSE" statements as the Microsoft Jet Engine doesn't allow me to do the same in Tableau.

Comment: When there are so many conditions that `Switch()` chokes, create a mapping table with a row for each combination of `[Subjectcode]` and text value.  Then join the mapping table into your query.

Comment: @HansUp - Thank you so much for your inputs. I would definitely implement it. However, are you aware of any other way to make it work?

Comment: Do you mean make `Switch()` accept all those cases which trigger the *"too complex"* complaint?  No, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I mean any other command than "Switch" that might work in this case?

Comment: I don't know.  In some situations, nested `IIf()` expressions can be a substitute for `Switch()`.  However I have no idea whether that would work here.  And I wouldn't even attempt it.  Join to a mapping table is the only reasonable approach IMO.

Comment: @HansUp - Thank you for your suggestion. I would move ahead with implementing the join to a mapping table.